# Question about returning a function as 'undefined' given a negative number?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write code that will return `undefined` if given a negative number

I was asked to calculate the areas of a rectangle, triangle and circle using a function in Javascript. I got that part right but the problem also says "*If any of the parameters are negative, the function should return undefined.*"

```
function calculateRectangleArea (length, width) {
  return length * width;
}
function calculateTriangleArea (base, height) {
  return (base * height)/2;
}
function calculateCircleArea (radius) {
  return radius * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

I can calculate the areas fine but I can't figure out what to write if there is a negative number to get `undefined`. Is it something like:

```
if (calculateRectangleArea <0) 
   return "undefined";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to test each parameter to make sure it's not negative, in an `if` statement, and if any are negative, return `undefined` - else, return the ordinary calculation like you're already doing:

```
function calculateRectangleArea(length, width) {
  if (length < 0 || width < 0) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return length * width;
  }
}
function calculateTriangleArea(base, height) {
  if (base < 0 || height < 0) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return (base * height) / 2;
  }
}
function calculateCircleArea(radius) {
  if (radius < 0) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return radius * radius * Math.PI;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, since when no value is returned, `undefined` is returned by default, you could also only return the calculation if all parameters are non-negative, eg:

```
function calculateRectangleArea(length, width) {
  if (length >= 0 && width >= 0) {
    return length * width;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could omit else, because if returned, no more flow is going on in the function.

Comment: You don't need the `else` statement, because `return` exits from the function - if it's not exited, then you can run the rest of the function because the return conditions were not met.

Comment: @guest271314 Then the return value is 0. OP's requirement said to return `undefined` on *negative* parameters, but didn't say anything about when parameters are 0, so presumably an output of 0 is desired

Answer (score 3):

Because you want it to happen if *any* of the parameters are undefined, use `some` on `[...arguments]`:

```
function calculateRectangleArea (length, width) {
  if ([...arguments].some(e => e < 0)) return undefined;
  return length * width;
}
```

Do this for all your functions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most readable solution is checking that all arguments are positive before calculating the area, otherwise you will return `undefined`.

For example (this is using the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)):

```
function calculateRectangleArea (length, width) {
  return length < 0 || width < 0 ? undefined: length * width;
}

function calculateTriangleArea (base, height) {
  return base < 0 || height < 0 ? undefined : (base * height)/2;
}

function calculateCircleArea (radius) {
  return radius < 0 ? undefined: radius * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

(Note: for the circle you could use the [exponential operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)), where supported)

Since you have defined a common pattern for all the calculations, you could generalize.

Basically, you could define a "guard" where you execute the given function only if the arguments are positive, otherwise you will return `undefined`. That kind of checking could be applied to all your calculations, despite the arguments and the math involved. That is possible because JS has [First-class functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function).

The following example is using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but they could be done with regular function too:

```
// Takes a function as argument and returns a function 
// that will execute the function given only if all the arguments
// provided are positive, `undefined` otherwise:
const guard = fn => (...args) => args.some(arg => arg < 0) ? undefined : fn(...args);

const calculateRectangleArea = guard((length, width) => length * width);
const calculateTriangleArea = guard((base, height) => base * height /2);
const calculateCircleArea = guard(radius => radius ** 2 * Math.PI);
```

Comment: I considered *"If any of the parameters are negative"* from the OP as if they're less than `0` in the code I suggested. However, you're right, this is not consistent with the first example I wrote, I'm going to invert the condition there so both examples will be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Math.abs()` to check if an integer or decimal is negative.
The code defines the functions as properties of an object, and a function
which uses `.find()` to create a variable which is set as `undefined` if one of the parameters passed to the function is negative

```js
const calculations = {
  calculateRectangleArea (length, width) {
    const n = this[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this)[0]](length, width) 
    return !n ? n : length * width
  },
  calculateTriangleArea (base, height) {
    const n = this[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this)[0]](base, height) 
    return !n ? n : (base * height)/2
  },
  calculateCircleArea (radius) { 
    const n = this[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this)[0]](radius) 
    return !n ? n : radius * radius * Math.PI
  },
  [Symbol('filter')](...props) {
    const n = props.find(n => Math.abs(n) !== n)
    // if `n` is not `undefined` `return` `void 0` else return `true`
    console.log(!n)
    return n !== undefined ? void 0 : !n
  }
}

console.log(
  calculations.calculateRectangleArea(0, 0) // `0`
, calculations.calculateTriangleArea(1, 2) // `1` 
, calculations.calculateCircleArea(-2, 1) // `undefined`
)
```

Comment: Not really. If length and width are both negative, then `n === Math.abs(n)` will return true.
OP needs to check "if any of the parameters are negative".

Comment: @KhauriMcClain OP can use the same `Math.abs()` evaluation for any, all of the parameters passed to the function.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer just doesn't make sense and I think you either misunderstood the original question or are trying to do something too clever. If for example OP were to use this to calculate `radius*radius*Math.PI` then if radius were passed in as -1, OP would want the function to return `undefined`. However, since `-1 * -1 * Math.PI == 1 * Math.PI` and `1 * Math.PI == Math.abs(1 * Math.PI)`, this function would not return undefined.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Did you not read the previous comment? There are existing answers which iterate all parameters passed; for example, using `arguments` and `Array.prototype.some()`. The answer demonstrates one option to check if an integer or decimal is negative.

Comment: I understand that your comment suggests for OP to use `n === Math.abs(n)` on every individual parameter of the function, but that's not reflected in your actual answer. Your actual answer seems to imply that OP should use this as a way to return undefined from the function, but this will only do so if the final calculation is negative, which isn't what the OP asked. 
And furthermore I don't understand why you would prefer to do this over a more understandable `n < 0`

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Ok. You have written your concerns relevant to the answer and have read those concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say thank you for all of this help! I managed to solve it but it is really helpful to have this community willing to step in and assist! I hope one day I will be good enough to return the favour.

Thanks!